# How do I set a Jetty WebDefault.xml so that all urls protected except but one pattern which does not require a password

Tags: security, solr, jetty, web.xml, basic-authentication

So far I have the code below so that users and admin have different priveleges which works, but I do not want a password at all for /solr/select/* . Is this possible or do I have to place every possible pattern except for the select pattern in the new_core-role

```
  <security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>Solr authenticated application</web-resource-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
  <role-name>new_core-role</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint> 
<web-resource-collection> 
    <web-resource-name>Public</web-resource-name> 
    <url-pattern>/solr/select/*</url-pattern> 
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>anyone-role</role-name>
        <role-name>new_core-role</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
<realm-name>User Realm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? Even I am looking for something where I could authenticate all but not select

Comment: yea I ended up using a proxy for SolrJ, I also restricted access to localhost only, that way any select requests from external ip addresses were not allowed, I don't think the web xml had the capability we were looking for

Comment: thanks for replyiing